# Additional/Made up roles in Resistance or Resistance avalon

Tags: the-resistance, the-resistance-avalon

My friends and I have started making up new roles for resistance when we get tired of using the basics like Merlin, Percival Mordred, Morgana and Oberon.

I know Mordred can hide from Merlin, Merlin knows who is evil(except Mordred), Morgana appears as Merlin, Percival know who is Merlin (and who is Morgana, but not which one is which), and Oberon is evil but he doesn't know who else is evil and they don't know who he is.

So far one variation we've played with is where Oberon knows who his evil team mates are, or they know who he is. He is evil, but knows nothing about who else is good and evil but his evil team mates will know who he is. Or he knows who all of them are, but they don't know who he is.

We've also played with "Nice Friends" (The name is a work in progress). Where two Loyal Servants know the identity of each other but nothing else, they don't know who any of the evil people are. And at the end of the game if the evil team can correctly guess both Nice Friends they win. Usually if we play with nice friends at least Percival is removed.

Has anyone made up their own roles, used any other variations or are there any that already exist that aren't in the traditional version of Avalon?

Comment: This question is about being creative, so I don't think it can ever avoid being opinion based. To close questions like this is closing out creativeness, which I don't think helps the community. Could we re-open this, maybe with the game-design tag added?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few we like to play with. Names are a work in progress, and you do have to think through how you combine these roles, some combinations can be unbalanced. Also, for some reason most of these are Good Characters.

### Oracle (Nimueh)

**Ability**: Once per round, (or once at the start of the game), can look at a single characters card.
**Best In:** Large games, where 5 cards isn't enough to know everything.
**Options:**

- If Evil kills Nimueh instead of Merlin, it's a draw.
- Instead of looking at a card, can look at one token a player in a mission has put.
- Could be an Evil player as well. Note: This requires some balancing, because otherwise seeing Merlin's card is an instant win. Best is Oracle has separate win conditions: Wins by Failing Enough Missions, but Loses if Merlin dies.

### King Arthur

**Ability:** At the start of the game, reveals his card. Is a Good player.
**Best In:** Smaller games, where his help in winning missions is cancelled out by making it easier to guess who Merlin is.
**Options:**

- Limited number of missions he can take part in. (One or Two is best)
- If he is on a losing mission, can no longer join missions. (Or, Good loses)

### Witch

**Ability:** Once per game, can change a Fail token to Success. However, the next turn, one Success Token is changed to Fail
**Best In:** Any game, but can be a bit OP in combo with Arthur.
**Options:**

- Sees tokens first, then changes.
- Can also change a Success to Fail first, and then change a Fail to Success at any later turn.
- Is an extra assigned role, meaning may be a Good or Evil character, or and one with another Role.

### Cupid

**Ability:** At the start of the game, chooses two people to be lovers. Lovers see each others Character Cards. If Good falls in love with Evil, then the Good player wins if Evil does.
**Best In:** Any game
**Options:**

- Instead of a Cupid character, start with a random pairing.
- Evil converts to Good because of love.

### Sir Robin

**Ability:** Is a Good Player, but can only play Fail Tokens.
**Best In:** Random Roles, i.e there may or may not be a Sir Robin in the game.

### The Rat

**Ability:** Is an Evil Player. When included in a mission, after all tokens have been played, the rat can look at the tokens and change his if he wants.
**Best In:** Medium to Large games, where he won't be able to use his ability too many times.

Answer (score 2):

We have quite an avid group (one player logged his thousandth game last month) and have experimented with quite a few alternative roles. Some are well known on BGG, some we've created or tweaked. I forget which are which now.

### Guinevere

Played with Good and Bad Lancelots. She sees them both, not knowing which is which, and can be chosen to assassinate instead of Merlin win the game, but it must be specified you are assassinating the player as Guinevere, or as Merlin.

> Call: Good and Bad Lancelot keeping your eyes closed, raise your thumbs. Guinevere open your eyes to see the 2 Lancelots. Guinevere close your eyes. Lancelots thumbs down.

*Recommend doing this at the start of the call, just before the bad guys. Therefore the call ends with "Good Lancelot lower your thumb. Bad Lancelot stay as you are."*

### Lovers

Similar idea to some of the suggestions in the answer by @Cain. Two good players who see each other. If used well, they can confuse the bad guys by coming off as a Merlin/Percival pairing. We use a male and female generic good card for these, which can be important during the call if you play the Love Triangle.

> Call: Lovers, raise your thumb, open your eyes, and blow a kiss at
> your lover. Lovers close your eyes and lower your thumbs.

### Love Triangle

An extension on the Lovers idea with a complicated call. Another character is added who is bad, Mark. Both lovers see their lover and Mark, so aren’t sure which is the one they trust. Much like Percival or Guinevere.

> Call: Lovers and Mark keeping your eyes closed raise your thumbs.
> Female lover open your eyes. Female lover close your eyes. Male lover
> open your eyes. Male lover close your eyes. Everybody thumbs down.

### Puck

An essentially good player, who wants a bit of chaos. Puck only wins with the Good team if they make it to, and win, the 5th round. Puck cannot out himself at any point. Makes for interesting logic when you get to the later rounds, as bad players can convince the good that previous fails were Puck, but Puck would now play a Success.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of quick points,

> Oberon: Does not reveal as evil and does not know who evil is

You are playing it exactly as it is set up in the rules

> Percival: Knows who Merlin is

While Merlin may not know who Percival is he does know who all good are and Percival knows who he is.

You should check out the rules for the optional characters for some other new roles

http://www.redmeeple.com/site/images/Rules/The_Resistance_Avalon_Rules(EN).pdf

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear I know about Merlin, Percival, Mordred, Morgana, and Oberon (Although you are correct I was playing with Oberon wrong). I was wondering about characters or roles above and beyond these, or variations that aren't in the normal rules. I'll update the question.